# How are my previous Python values being overwritten in this dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to update a dictionary, but the previous values keep getting overwritten. Here's a shortened version of the code I'm using.

```
selected_session = ""
encounters_to_add = []
session_encounters = {}

selected_session = "Session 1: Paint it Black"
encounters_to_add.append("Meet the Town (Narrative)")
session_encounters[selected_session] = encounters_to_add

encounters_to_add.append("Barn Bandits (Structured)")
session_encounters[selected_session] = encounters_to_add

encounters_to_add.clear()
selected_session = "Session 2: Myster Man"
encounters_to_add.append("A Crime Most Foul (Social)")
session_encounters[selected_session] = encounters_to_add

print(session_encounters)
```

I'm trying to return

```
{'Session 1: Paint it Black': ['Meet the Town (Narrative)', 'Barn Bandits (Structured)'], 'Session 2: Mystery Man': ['A Crime Most Foul (Social)']}
```

Instead, I get back

```
{'Session 1: Paint it Black': ['A Crime Most Foul (Social)'], 'Session 2: Myster Man': ['A Crime Most Foul (Social)']}
```

I don't understand how the previous value is being overwritten. Since I'm using a new key, the values should just be added to that key in my mind.

Comment: You're adding _the same list_ as the value for each key. Every time you `clear` it, and then `append` to it, you're of course changing that list. What you want to do is create a _new list_ for each one, instead of clearing and reusing the same one. For example, `encounters_to_add = []`.

Comment: You can also try using `defaultdict(list)` to store dictionary with `list` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are just storing a ***reference*** to the list instance that you create in your second line:

```
# Creates a new instance of a list where
# 'encounters_to_add' is the reference to this list
encounters_to_add = []  
# Stores only a copy of the 'reference' in your dictionary
session_encounters[selected_session] = encounters_to_add
```

***It is not a copy of the list*** - which seems to be what you are assuming - but a copy of the reference to that list.

Anything you do to `encounters_to_add` will affect `session_encounters[selected_session]` because

```
session_encounters[selected_session] = encounters_to_add
session_encounters[selected_session] is encounters_to_add # is True
```

or a little more clearly:

```
session_encounters['A'] = encounters_to_add
session_encounters['B'] = encounters_to_add

session_encounters['A'] is encounters_to_add # is True
session_encounters['B'] is encounters_to_add # is also True
```

---

You need two instances, for example:

```
encounters_to_add_1 = []  # An instance of a list
encounters_to_add_2 = []  # Another list instance

session_encounters = {}

selected_session = "Session 1: Paint it Black"
encounters_to_add_1.append("Meet the Town (Narrative)")
encounters_to_add_1.append("Barn Bandits (Structured)")
session_encounters[selected_session] = encounters_to_add_1   

selected_session = "Session 2: Myster Man"
encounters_to_add_2.append("A Crime Most Foul (Social)")
session_encounters[selected_session] = encounters_to_add_2

print(session_encounters)
```

outputs:

```
{'Session 1: Paint it Black': ['Meet the Town (Narrative)', 'Barn Bandits (Structured)'], 'Session 2: Myster Man': ['A Crime Most Foul (Social)']}
```

---

Here is another example - try to find out what happens here:

```
my_list = list()
my_dict = {i: my_list for i in range(3)}
my_dict[0].append('Hello World!')
print(my_dict)

my_dict = {i: list() for i in range(3)}
my_dict[0].append('Hello World!')
print(my_dict)
```

Why do you get:

```
{0: ['Hello World!'], 1: ['Hello World!'], 2: ['Hello World!']}
{0: ['Hello World!'], 1: [], 2: []}
```

Comment: The last example may be a bit confusing because of the dict-comprehension there. It might be a bit clearer if you just added the list three times without comprehension or loop.

Comment: @MSeifert I am using it on purpose because OP seems to be a student/learner and I'm confident that he'll find out what it does :)

Comment: This solution is not scalable as you will need to keep creating new lists for every new encounter key. The right way to fix that is to pass the list by value and reuse it again. I have added a solution to illustrate how to achieve that below.

Comment: @helcode Why do you think it's not scalable? It has the advantage that it only creates 2 lists, while reusing and copying creates 3 (one original and two copies), so it's "more scalable".

Comment: @MSeifert What if I need to build a dictionary of 100? your proposal mandates that we create `_1, _2 ... _100` lists in code and then statically assign them into the dictionary. A scalable solution should allow us to iterate on inputs and build the outputs with no code changes.

Comment: @helcode This example obviously just highlights the issue towards a student. A *scalable* solution, as you call it, is not required here. Speaking of (your solution), clearing a list, re-assigning new items and then copying this entire list is also not very efficient.

Comment: I don't think your solution of using different lists qualify as a resolution towards a student. The question is about adding/updating values in a dictionary "persistently" using a single List `encounters_to_add `. your "solution" is to use multiple lists.

Comment: @helcode I don't fully agree. The question is about "*why is the previous value overwritten*" and my answer addresses just that. Anything else is irrelevant in this context. I did not intend to write a nice, clean and "scaleable" solution but explain to the OP *what* he is seeing and *why*. What is interesting though is that not even your own answer shows what you are demanding from my answer (iteratively constructing a dictionary on inputs) . I wonder why.

Answer (score 1):

You have just **one list** that you insert into the dictionary 3 times, the second insert overwrites the first so in fact the same list is only present two times in the end. In between adding you also clear it, that's why you lose the two original entries. Just add a `print(session_encounters)` just after the `clear()` call.

To walk you through your example step by step:

```
selected_session = ""
encounters_to_add = []
session_encounters = {}

selected_session = "Session 1: Paint it Black"
encounters_to_add.append("Meet the Town (Narrative)")
session_encounters[selected_session] = encounters_to_add
```

[image]

```
encounters_to_add.append("Barn Bandits (Structured)")
session_encounters[selected_session] = encounters_to_add
```

[image]

```
encounters_to_add.clear()
```

[image]

```
selected_session = "Session 2: Myster Man"
encounters_to_add.append("A Crime Most Foul (Social)")
session_encounters[selected_session] = encounters_to_add
```

[image]

The solution is simple: Always create new lists:

```
session_encounters = {}

selected_session = "Session 1: Paint it Black"
encounters_to_add = ["Meet the Town (Narrative)", "Barn Bandits (Structured)"]
session_encounters[selected_session] = encounters_to_add

selected_session = "Session 2: Myster Man"
encounters_to_add  ["A Crime Most Foul (Social)"]
session_encounters[selected_session] = encounters_to_add

print(session_encounters)
```

Note that you could also use `collections.defaultdict` to make this a bit more straight-forward:

```
from collections import defaultdict

session_encounters = defaultdict(list)
session_encounters["Session 1: Paint it Black"].append("Meet the Town (Narrative)")
session_encounters["Session 1: Paint it Black"].append("Barn Bandits (Structured)")
session_encounters["Session 2: Myster Man"].append("A Crime Most Foul (Social)")

print(session_encounters)
```

Answer (score 0):

In python, there are two ways to pass/assign values, **by-reference** or **by-value**.

1. **Pass-by-Reference**: The object receives an implicit reference to the object pointing to the original location of the value. By default, mutable objects will be passed-by-reference. (ex. Lists)
2. **Pass-by-Value**: A local copy of the value will be created and linked to the object. By default, immutable objects will be passed-by-value (ex. Integers, Strings, etc.)

   > Update (Credit to **MSeifert**): Please note that Python by default will always assign value **by-reference**. the pass-by-value described above is actually a behavior happened due to the immutability of some object types. Read into the comments for more details/examples.

The problem you are facing is that you passed `encounters_to_add` list **by-reference** into the dictionary `sessions_encounters` and then reset the object using `encounters_to_add.clear()` method. Which affected all object associations (including the value associated with the key `"Session 1: Paint it Black"` inside the `session_encounters` dictionary).

In order to fix that, you will need to pass `encounters_to_add` by value as per the code below,

> Notice that the only difference is in the assignment at line `session_encounters[selected_session] = encounters_to_add[:]` where `[:]` will instruct python to make a local copy of the list (pass-by-value) rather than pass it by reference.

```
selected_session = ""
encounters_to_add = []
session_encounters = {}

selected_session = "Session 1: Paint it Black"
encounters_to_add.append("Meet the Town (Narrative)")

encounters_to_add.append("Barn Bandits (Structured)")
session_encounters[selected_session] = encounters_to_add[:]

encounters_to_add.clear()
selected_session = "Session 2: Myster Man"
encounters_to_add.append("A Crime Most Foul (Social)")
session_encounters[selected_session] = encounters_to_add[:]

print(session_encounters)
```

This will output,

```
{'Session 1: Paint it Black': ['Meet the Town (Narrative)', 'Barn Bandits (Structured)'], 'Session 2: Myster Man': ['A Crime Most Foul (Social)']}
```

Comment: There's no pass-by-value in Python, there are just references (even integers are references). And pass-by-shallow copy is a bit wasteful here. You could simply create new lists as needed, no need to (shallow) copy everything.

Comment: Can you provide a reference to your claim "there is not pass by value in Python"?

My proof, let's assume `a=5`, `b=a`, `a=7`, `print(b)` will yield to `5` because the `a=b` has been passed by value. so how come python doesn't support pass-by-value :)

Comment: That's just a proof that names and values/references are different things. In your example you don't assign names (you don't assign the name b to a), you assign references (you assign the reference of a to b). There's a truly great talk (and write-up) about it: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html). You might be interested in the section that follows "Fact: Names are reassigned independently of other names."

Comment: @MSeifert Thanks for the nice reading. The section you referenced **Fact: Names are reassigned independently of other names** is actually stating that value gets copied between immutable objects. I understand your point though that due to that fact integers are immutable, the new assignment is actually a rewrite of the object. Hence, referencing my example of (`a=5`, `b=a`, `a=7`), `print(b)` will yield `5` because `a` has been referenced to a new value `7` leaving `b` immutable at its original value. I'll update my answer to reference that. Thanks for the insight.